# Reducing a linear algebra expression to quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, machine-learning

I am trying to solve the following exercise for my Machine Learning course.

> Expand this expression so that there are only quadratic terms:
>
> $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu})^T
> \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu} )
> +
> (\mathbf{\mu} - \mathbf{\mu_0})^T
> \mathbf{S}^{-1} ( \mathbf{\mu} - \mathbf{\mu_0}  )
> $
>
> Where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\mu}_0$ are vectors and $\Sigma^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{S}^{-1}$ are square, invertible matrices.

Now, doing some research, I found out that the quadratic form is a matrix that can be produced in the form $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$

Unfortunately after a few operations, the expression cannot be made better than this (is that correct?):

$
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{x} - 
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{\mu} -
\mathbf{\mu}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{x} +
\mathbf{\mu}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{\mu} + 
\mathbf{\mu}^T\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{\mu} -
\mathbf{\mu}_0^T\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{\mu} +
\mathbf{\mu}_0^T\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{\mu}_0 -
\mathbf{\mu}^T\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{\mu}_0 
$

As you can see it's not just quadratic terms. Vectors, such as $\mathbf{x}$,  $\mathbf{\mu}$ and $\mathbf{\mu}_0$, are sometimes both present in terms that are not in quadratic form. What I am missing?

(a naive side question: since the quadratic form is used to represent non-linear expression, can this still be called *linear* algebra?)

Comment: Given the conventional notation, I'm going to take a stab and suspect that $\Sigma$ and $S$ are skew-symmetric. Am I right?